# Device not identified as removable

Tags: kde, udev, devices

I have an ebook reader (Kobo Aura) that used to appear as a removable device when connected (in KDE's device notifier). Some time in the last month or so (I haven't upgraded the device), it has changed, and now it appears as a non-removable device, so I have to change the device notifier settings in order to see it and mount it.

Can I do anything to have the device be recognized as removable again?

Additional info:

The device has an external SD card. The internal memory appears as sdb (not removable), the external card as sdc (removable).

I can boot up the device using an alternative system (Kobo Start Menu), and in this case the internal memory appears as removable, still sdb. With `dmesg` the only difference I see between the different methods is different serial number and product id (this is because the alternative method uses a third-party software in the device).

As suggested by some comments, I've looked at `cat /sys/block/sdb/removable`, and it says `1` (for sdc too). It has also been suggested that udev may be the culprit, however `udevadm info --a --name /dev/sdb` says `ATTR{removable}=="1"` (I'm not sure that's meaningful, though).

Comment: I did some research and cannot come up with anything.  Please [edit] your question and add the info that cat `/sys/block/sdb/removable` gives a '1'...  Delete all the other comments to keep things uncluttered.  I'll vote up your question to attract more people... (and I've added the udev tag as I think the problem is there but don't know enough about it)